# How can I recover the SOL used for rent after a failed Solana program deployment?

Tags: solana

I tried to deploy a Solana program, it failed, and I lost my SOL that I used for rent. Is there any way to get it back?

```
Error: Deploying program failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0x1
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes! The SOL you used for rent is still stored in the account, even if the deployment failed.

### To recover the SOL from one deployment

After your deployment fails, you'll get an error like this:

```
Recover the intermediate account's ephemeral keypair file with
`solana-keygen recover` and the following 12-word seed phrase:
=================================================================================
this is a fake seed phrase really argle bargle boopity doop face
=================================================================================
To resume a deploy, pass the recovered keypair as the
[BUFFER_SIGNER] to `solana program deploy` or `solana write-buffer'.
Or to recover the account's lamports, pass it as the
[BUFFER_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS] argument to `solana program close`.
=================================================================================
```

First recover the keypair from the seed phrase that it gave you:

```sh
# After running this, paste in the seed phrase above
solana-keygen recover -o recover.json
```

Then you can close the account to recover your SOL.

```sh
solana program close recover.json
```

## To recover SOL from ALL in-progress or failed deployments

Alternatively, you can recover the SOL from all in-progress deployments by running:

```
solana program close --buffers
```

Comment: Seems like I cannot send my Sol out of the recovery address, even though I was able to load it into my phantom wallet